Find the minimum number of send/recv actions in directed communication graph
Given p processes and n packages. Every process contains k = n / p distinct packages. Now, I want to re-distribute these packages among these processes according to a surjective mapping f. After the operation, each package is assigned to exactly one process and every process contains the same number of packages k. The mapping f is known to all processes.
Every process has two actions:

send(n, p) sends package n to process p. When performing this action, the process is waiting for the remote side to be ready, and then sends the data. While executing this action, the state of the process is s_send.
recv(p) receives a package from process p. When performing this action, the process is waiting for the remote side to be ready, and then reads the incoming data. While executing this action, the state of the process is s_recv.

Every process can be in one state at a time, thus, the actions must be performed in sequence. The actions of processes must match, i.e., p1 must send(n, p2) while p2 is recv(p1)ing.
My problem now is to find a sequence of communication actions a[1], ..., a[m] for every process p, such that the data is exchanged according to f in the minimal number of steps.
Are there similar problems in computer science that this problem can be reduced to? Are there any existing solutions? Or is it NP-hard?
I thought about depicting this as a communication graph with processes 0..p-1 as the nodes and each communication operation as a directed edge between them, labeled by the package. For any connected component in this graph, I could try to identify a round trip of maximum length. Each such round-trip corresponds to one send and recv action for every process, i.e., in the first step, every second process is in s_send, while the remaining are in s_recv; in the second step, the states reverse. After having completed the communication, I remove the respective edges from the graph and repeat until there are no edges left. However, I believe there might be a better, more standard, more performant solution?
Example: We have 8 nodes, denoted by 0 to 7, and 16 messages, denoted by a to p. The communication graph is
0  -- a -->  0  (no communication)
   -- i -->  4
1  -- b -->  0
   -- j -->  4
2  -- c -->  1
   -- k -->  5
3  -- d -->  1
   -- l -->  5
4  -- e -->  2
   -- m -->  6
5  -- f -->  2
   -- n -->  6
6  -- g -->  3
   -- o -->  7
7  -- h -->  3
   -- p -->  7 (no communication)

Action sequence, grouped by circles:

circle 0 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0:

0->send(i, 4), 6->send(o, 7), 3->send(l, 5), 2->send(c, 1)
4->send(m, 6), 7->send(h, 3), 5->send(f, 2), 1->send(b, 0)


circle 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 3 -> 1:

1->send(j, 4), 2->send(k, 5), 6->send(g, 3)
4->send(e, 2), 5->send(n, 6), 3->send(d, 1)



Thus, this communication needs 4 time steps.

Instead explicitly searching for circles or longest paths through the graph G, it's much easier to view this problem from a slightly different angle. At every time step, each node can be in either one of two states: s_send or s_recv. If a node v is in s_send, at least one neighboring node v' with an edge (v, v') must be in state s_recv. Similarly, if v is in state s_recv, at least one neighboring node v' with an edge (v', v) must be in state s_send. This is equivalent to regarding the edge (v, v') or (v', v) as "active", respectively. When an edge (v, v') is active, all other edges connected to either v or v' cannot be active at the same time because both nodes can only either send or receive data over a single connection.
This problem is equivalent to the two-coloring problem on the edge graph. I define the edge graph of a graph G = (V, E) as the undirected graph Gₑ = (Vₑ, Eₑ) where Vₑ = E and E = {(vₑ, vₑ') | vₑ, vₑ' ∈ Vₑ ∧ vₑ ≠ vₑ' ∧ vₑ ∩ vₑ' ≠ ∅}, i.e., the nodes represent edges in the original graph and the nodes that represent edges with exactly one common node are connected.
The algorithm for finding the communication plan P is:
function FIND-COMMUNICATION-PLAN(G):
  Gₑ = COMPUTE-EDGE-GRAPH(G)
  P = {}
  while Gₑ ≠ ∅:
    Cᵢ, Cⱼ ← TWO-COLOR(Gₑ)
    P ← P ∪ {Cᵢ}
    Gₑ ← REMOVE-NODES(Gₑ, Cᵢ)
    P ← P ∪ {Cⱼ}
    Gₑ ← REMOVE-NODES(Gₑ, Cⱼ)
  end
  return P
end

Cᵢ and Cⱼ are sets of edges in G (or nodes in Gₑ) with color i and j, respectively. These represent two successive communication phases. After adding these to the set of communication phases, these colored edges are removed from the edge graph and the process is repeated until no nodes are left in the edge graph. The output of this algorithm is a set of communication phases, each being a set of directed edges (v, v') ∈ V that are active at the same time.
Solving the two-coloring problem on this undirected graph is simple: Starting from a random node, walk through the graph in breadth-first manner and color each node in the opposite color than its neighbors.
If the graph is not fully connected, I run the breadth-first search on each connected component. If the graph cannot satisfy the two-color problem, I introduce a third color "unset" that is compatible with both colors, and just ignore this color in FIND-COMMUNICATION-PLAN.
Since I select the starting node for breadth-first search at random, I currently do not necessarily get the minimal number of communication rounds, it's sometimes off by one, so I may want to optimize this.
This algorithm will always terminate because at least one vₑ can be assigned a color, so each call to TWO-COLOR will output at least one node. It runs in O(|V| * |P|) time. The worst-case scenario is a graph where each node is only connected to the same node, i.e., E = {(v, v') | v' ∈ V ∧ v' ≠ v} for a v ∈ V. In this case, |P| = |V| - 1 and the runtime becomes O(|V|²).
